# Floating point addition 5-bit

Tags: binary

Bit pattern 1: 10010

Bit pattern 2: 11001

Can anyone show me or explain to me how to solve this 5-bit addition?

Comment: Do you want addition or multiplication? Because it says addition in your title but multiplication in your text...

Comment: oh, i'm sorry, it's addition

Comment: https://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~eedwards/compsys/float/ does this help?